# Distribution combinations

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations, normal-distribution, combinations

How many ways can $25$ identical pencils be distributed between two people? Each pencil must be given out.

a) Each person must have at least $5$ pencils.

b) Each person must have at least $7$ pencils.

c) Each person must have at least $10$ pencils.

Thank you for your input of wisdom.

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

If each of A and B must have $5$ pencils at least, give them each $5$ pencils. That leaves $15$ pencils. We can give $0$ of these to A, or $1$, or $2$, and so on up to $15$.

The other questions are done in exactly the same way.